# Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Ruby-on-Rails app the needs to use mysql2. When I try to run the app, I get the following error:

> Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the sources

If I run `bundle install` I get the following error:

> An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.

Finally, if I try to run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` I get this error:

> ERROR:  Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try running `bundle install --verbose` and see if you can get more logging information.  The mysql gem compiles some C, and that's probably what's failing.  A likely culprit is not having development libraries for MySQL installed (look for a package like libmysql or mysql-devel; depends on your OS).  Running with `--verbose` should tell you what directory it's trying to build in.  You can go to that directory and run `make` manually and see more detailed logging about the build.

Comment: please, tell us your OS! The problem seems to be platform-specific, as it cannot build native extensions`